# Information on communication between hardware devices and computers

Tags: serial-port, usb, driver, protocols, serial-communication

currently I got the task to write a python program to read out measurement devices. I have some trouble fulfilling this task. Right now I try to understand how the communication between drivers, devices and computers in detail (serial devices, USB in particular). I already invested a few weeks searching for information in literature (Internet and library). Indeed, I wasn't succesful. The information I got were either far too detailed or too general. I wanted to ask if someone could recommend me good information sources for this topic.

This is my first post in Stackoverflow. I hope this question is not too general or misplaced for this communitiy, if so I am very sorry.

Comment: This question is way to general. What device are you talking about? Is it a single one? Is it a group? The datasheets for the device should give you an idea about the protocol it uses. Also the vendor should be able to provide you the details on the communication for their device.

Comment: first if you want to communicate with a serial device from your PC you probably need a serial to USB converter (RS232 to USB). But this depends on your device. Also if you want to write your code in Python there is the [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) library which I heard is a good start. Also as @MarkusDeibel stated you will need to get the protocol which the device uses.